# Skrill: What is correct way to create recurring billing profile in Skrill

Tags: skrill

I am trying to generate a recurring payment using our test accounts and I am getting response on status url as well which is mentioned below.

Implemented as per [Instructions](https://www.skrill.com/fileadmin/content/pdf/Skrill_Wallet_Checkout_Guide.pdf) which are mentioned on page number: 12 & 35

Here is the code which we are posting to Skrill:

```
<form action="https://pay.skrill.com" target="_blank" class="skrill-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="pay_to_email" value="email@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="http://domain/dev-test-page-2/">
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url_text" value="Return to main website">
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url_target" value="4">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="http://domain/dev-test-page-2/">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url_target" value="4">
    <input type="hidden" name="status_url"
           value="http://domain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=skrill_response">
    <input type="hidden" name="status_url2" value="mailto:email@gamil.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="logo_url" value="https://domain/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/logo.png">
    <input type="hidden" name="rec_amount" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="rec_start_date" value="17/01/2019">
    <input type="hidden" name="rec_end_date" value="27/01/2019">
    <input type="hidden" name="rec_period" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="rec_cycle" value="day">
    <input type="hidden" name="rec_grace_period" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="rec_status_url"
           value="http://domain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=skrill_rec_status_url">
    <input type="hidden" name="rec_status_url2"
           value="http://domain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=skrill_rec_status_url">
    <input type="text" name="amount" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Pay" class="btn">
</form>
```

Response:

```
    [action] => skrill_response
    [transaction_id] => 2605308006
    [mb_amount] => 39
    [amount] => 39
    [md5sig] => 72EE69AA174B377A6E488129CA4F5063
    [merchant_id] => 111682769
    [payment_type] => WLT
    [mb_transaction_id] => 2605308006
    [mb_currency] => EUR
    [pay_from_email] => email@gmail.com
    [pay_to_email] => email@gmail.com
    [currency] => EUR
    [customer_id] => 111683528
    [status] => 2
```

We are not getting any response on rec_status_url. Further, we have also tried to access the recurring transaction status of above test transaction as per mentioned instructions in PDF in return I received an email that my account temporarily locked.

Am I skipping some of essential parameters?

Query string as per instructions to access the status of a recursion:

```
https://www.skrill.com/app/query.pl?action=status_rec&email=email@gmail.com&password=123456&trn_id=2605308006
```

Response:

```
401 Your account is currently locked. Please contact our Merchant Team at:merchantservices@skrill.com
```

Implemented as per [Instructions](https://www.skrill.com/fileadmin/content/pdf/Skrill_Automated_Payments_Interface_Guide.pdf) which are mentioned on page number: 30

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved your issue?

Most probably you merchant account is not enabled from Skrill's side to receive recurring payments. Please ask their support to enable it for you.
Also i would highly recommend you to user server-to-server request to generate 'session' for your payments, not leaving your payment parameters/data on the user's front-end(html form).

As far as i am aware about rec_status_url, it should be called only in when customer was subscribed and there was at least one sub/recurring payment, then if he cancels the plan, you should receive correct http post message.

About query.pl?action=status_rec - all MQI/API queries should contain your MQI/API password as md5 hash value - not plain text password.
Make sure that "MQI" service is enabled for your account(My Account->Settings->Developer Settings)

Cheers,